# mac machine No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

The angular application is running fine in windows machine but same application is not working on Mac. I am getting the below error in Mac. can you tell me why

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sports.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.


       if(window.location.hostname == "localhost"){
            this.sportsURL = 'http://sports.com/';
        }else{
            this.sportsURL = window.location.protocol+'//'+ window.location.hostname+ "/";
        }
```

Comment: Without more detail, nobody else can tell what's going on. Can you post the code that's calling the request? What browser are you using? Is that URL in the error message snippet you posted correct?

Comment: @ChristopherRonning hey can you tell me which file i need to post...since I see so many files...its a big appication

Comment: the one that is making a request to sports.com lol

Comment: @texirv what WilomGfx said

Comment: @ChristopherRonning hello updated the code

Comment: @WilomGfx  hello updated the code